# How to enable cross app authentication for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, facebook-login, keychain, gigya

Is there a method for cross app authentication in iOS that allows a user who has an authenticated session with one app to get authenticated for another app from the same developer? It works pretty nicely for the Facebook app and Facebook messenger on iOS, but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: You would typically share a keychain item using an application group

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps